# Preventing scale difference between `ListAnimate` and `Export`

Tags: export, animation, visualization

So I have the following animation which looks fine on screen:

```
b = 1;
makePlot[\[Theta]_] := 
  ContourPlot3D[{Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]} . {x, y} == 0, {x, -b, 
    b}, {y, -b, b}, {z, -b, b}, PlotPoints -> 60, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
   MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, Norm[{x, y, z}, 1] - 1], 
   Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshShading -> {Red, None}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   ViewPoint -> {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]], 0}, Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> None, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"];
plots = makePlot /@ Table[t, {t, 0, Pi/2, Pi/20}];
ListAnimate[plots]
```

However, when I export it with `Export["~/Desktop/test.gif", plots]`, it changes scale as seen below. Any tips how to make enforce consistency?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ContourPlot3D[..., SphericalRegion -> True]`.

[image]